# Automatically sync to a web server?

Tags: web, upload, server, synchronization

I have a web server with websites on it and I was just wondering if there is anyway of me being able to develop the websites on my Linux (Ubuntu) desktop PC and whenever I hit save it uploads it to the web server?

I hope you understand what I am trying to do.

Thanks

Comment: This depends mostly on your IDE - and if you really want to risk auto-uploading changes that could break your (live) website. I'd guess the most common solution is to have your source control system handle this.

Comment: Its currently only for personal use so I don't mind. I use Sublime.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this, using an advanced IDE.

For example a free and powerful one is NetBeans.

Essentially you need an FTP server on your host machine, then in NB you need to create a new project from external source, set up your FTP connection and that's about it, now every time you hit that <kbd>ctrl+s</kbd>, changes will be saved on your server as well.

Comment: I don't use an IDE as I'm a web designer.

Comment: @Kieron606 What you're saying sounds ridiculous. I just showed you an example, you need to research whether what you are using supports such functionality and if not switch to something that does.

Comment: @Kieron606 so, basically you want other people to do your research for you? Furthermore this question is off topic.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking about is called continuous delivery. Jenkins is a popular tool that can automatically test and deploy anything you save (or commit to svn or git).